# XSD - Enforce that a sub-tag is present?

Tags: xsd

This is a pretty simple question, but my Google skills haven't gotten me the answer yet, so:

Can an XSD enforce that an element MUST BE PRESENT within a higher level element?  I know that you can allow or disallow "explicit setting to nil" but that doesn't sound like the same thing.

For example:

```
<parentTag>
    <childTag1>
        ... stuff
    </childTag1>
    <childTag2>   <!-- FAIL VALIDATION IF a childTag2 isn't in parentTag!!! -->
        ... stuff
    </childTag2>
</parentTag>
```

If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements in an XSD are required to be present by default. If unspecified, the child element's [`minOccurs`](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/el_element.asp) property is set to 1.

That is, you must explicitly make an element *optional* by setting `minOccurs="0"`.

**Example schema**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="parentTag">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="childTag1" minOccurs="0"/> <!-- This element is optional -->
      <xs:element name="childTag2"/> <!-- This element is required -->
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**Testing valid XML (using xmllint)**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parentTag>
  <childTag1>
        <!-- ... stuff -->
  </childTag1>
  <childTag2>
        <!-- ... stuff -->
  </childTag2>
</parentTag>
```

```
testfile.xml validates
```

**Testing invalid XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<parentTag>
  <childTag1>
        <!-- ... stuff -->
  </childTag1>
</parentTag>
```

```
testfile.xml:2: element parentTag: Schemas validity error : Element 'parentTag': Missing child element(s). Expected is ( childTag2 ).
testfile.xml fails to validate
```

Comment: +1, although `minOccurs="1"` is the default, there's no need to specify it explicitly.